Revelation 3:21-22 Will Christians sit on the throne of the Father? Am I understanding this correctly?

Revelation 3:21 To him that overcometh will I grant to sit with me in
my throne, even as I also overcame, and am set down with my Father in
his throne.

Will the elect sit on the throne of the Father, or only on the throne of Jesus Christ The Messiah?
Some people tell me only The Father & The Son may sit therein, but I believe the words in the verse say otherwise.

John 10:30 I and my Father are one.


Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and functioning of the site. Your question up-voted +1.

The promise in Rev 3:21 applies only to those in the Laodicean church (whoever they are); but compare with Eph 2:6.

In Revelation 3:21-22, Jesus promises that those who overcome will be granted the right to sit with Him on His throne, just as He overcame and sat with His Father on His Father’s throne. This promise is profound, and to understand it fully, we must look at similar passages, each offering a deeper theological insight into what it means for Christians to partake in the divine throne.
First, consider Matthew 19:28, where Jesus promises His disciples that they will sit on twelve thrones, judging the twelve tribes of Israel. This passage suggests a type of co-regency with Christ, where believers are honored with authority alongside Him in a position of divine governance. Such an arrangement implies that those faithful to Christ share in His rule, though it does not imply equality with the Father or Son in divine nature but rather participation in Christ's authority.
Moreover, in Revelation 1:6, believers are described as a "kingdom and priests" unto God. Every king, of course, has a throne, symbolizing authority, and the priestly role speaks to a close communion with the divine. This priestly kingship means that believers, as temples of the Holy Spirit, hold a sanctified and exalted position. They act as mediators and representatives of divine rule, but their authority is derived from and subordinate to that of Christ, the ultimate High Priest and King.
In 1 John 4:15, we read, “If anyone acknowledges that Jesus is the Son of God, God lives in them and they in God.” This indwelling establishes believers as temples of God, which aligns with the notion of believers as "tabernacles" for Christ and the Spirit. Jesus, as the true tabernacle of the invisible, Almighty God (John 1:14), fulfills the divine presence among humanity. At the resurrection of the just, believers will be perfected and fully become tabernacles for Jesus and the Holy Spirit, sharing His glorified state and embodying His presence in a purified and holy way.
This understanding is concordant with 2 Peter 1:4, which speaks of believers becoming "partakers of the divine nature." Through God's promises, believers are granted access to this divine nature, escaping the corruption in the world and being transformed into vessels that reflect God's own character. This "partaking" does not mean an absorption into divinity, but rather a sharing in God’s holiness and glory through Jesus Christ, making it possible to reign with Him as co-heirs. Thus, the promise of sharing Christ’s throne is an invitation to participate in the divine life and authority, reflecting a profound unity with Christ without compromising the distinction between Creator and creation.

I am not clear what fully become tabernacles for Jesus means. Are you saying that Jesus Christ will not, himself,, be bodily present ? Only as within his people ?

It cannot be so, for the very book of Revelation states that the Lamb is the lamp of the city (Revelation 21:23), and it is precisely this light emanating from them that will fill the righteous as tabernacles.

So you do not accept the bodily resurrection of the Lord Jesus and his bodily ascension into the heaven of heavens ?

@NigelJ - that is an unnecessary extrapolation that does not necessarily follow from Betho's reasoning.

We accept the bodily resurrection of the Lord Jesus and His bodily ascension into the highest heaven. I am a baptized Roman Catholic, but I have never spoken on behalf of the Church. I am not a theologian. My intelligence level is average; I don’t hold a doctorate (PhD) in my field, only a post-graduate specialization.

@Betho's I am not attacking what you have said. But I am attempting to clarify an ambiguity. I believe that the resurrection and ascension of Christ results in his physical presence when he returns and in his physical presence in the new heavens and the new earth. And I wondered if that is what you, yourself, believe.

If a believer has heard the message of the truth “The Almost To Good To Be True News” and upon hearing it you (Christian) receive it by faith you have been delivered by Grace. After hearing Gods plan of Salvation and all that’s been made available to us (Believers) through the finished works of our Lord and Savior you can’t help but to fall in love with The King Of Kings And The Lord Of Lords! A person who comes to believe and acknowledges that He is Lord and trust in their heart that God raised Him from the dead the Promise of (Revelation 3:10-11) enters into that believers life, Our God will deliver us from this present evil age of what’s to come (Heb 9:35) He is Faithful and He will do it! Maintaining a renewed mind free from a conscious of sin is vital  (Heb 9:13-14) I urge you to remain steadfast of mind (Heb 10:18-23)
Right believing is what will give you the full assurance that you are already seated in heaven on the throne with Jesus (Eph 2:6) If believers could get a hold of this truth and get spiritually educated in the New Covenant it would be said of us “There Are Giants In The Land”. Right believing will make you a spiritual giant. When a Christian comes to know their identity and their heart is established in Righteousness they are maturing in the ministry of righteousness and have come to believe that God no longer sees their unrighteousness their sin and wicked evil deeds He remembers no more. Then it’s time to start praying and asking Him to give you a spirit of wisdom and revelation (Eph 1:16-18) in the knowledge of Him.
Once you get a revelation of these truths and come to believe your inner man is sealed with the promised Holy Spirit. You’ll come to realize that through Jesus you’ve been blessed with every spiritual blessing in heaven (Eph 1:3) It won’t be hard to believe that the same power that God used to raise Jesus from the dead is working in you.
I’m telling once you make a conscious decision and grow in the faith that comes from knowing Jesus you’re on your way. Without faith it’s impossible to please God (Heb 11:6) For a Christian to approach Him they must trust/believe that He does exist and that He becomes a rewarder to those who seek Him out. The power of God has already given us believers everything we’ll will ever need for life and godliness (2Peter 1:1-4)
In (Eph 6:2) Spiritual law declares that God raised “US” up together and made “US” sit together with Yeshua/Jesus and seated “US” with Him in “Heaven” far above all spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly realm. We’re already seated with Him on His throne at the Right Hand of the Father, (The Place Of Authority) we don’t have to wait for (Revelation 3:20-22) When Jesus won the “Victory” so did we!
You see “WE” have the right to use “HIS NAME” (Mark 16:17-19) “All” authority has been given to “US” who believe. The devil knows once a Christian gets a revelation of this he’s through! We believers have dominion/authority in 3 Realms/Worlds 1# (ON THE EARTH) 2# (ABOVE THE EARTH) 3#(UNDER THE EARTH/Hell) Adam and Eve only had dominion/authority in 1 Realm/World 1#(EARTH) Should the Body of Christ as a whole would come to know this “It would be said of us by the unbelieving world “There Are Giant’s In The Land” A God Worshipping, Right Believing,Tongue Talking, Spirit Filled Believer will never look to victory “NO” They  Can Only Stand In It! This Kind of Believer Never Looks To The Cross-They Only Look From It! Reason being is because they believe that through His/Jesus faith they have become the righteousness of God created in holiness. Praise God Forevermore “The Greater One” lives in us! As He Is My Brothers And Sisters In Heaven; So Are We On The Earth! I leave you with the prayer of Ephesians 3:16-19 Shalom יהרה

I find it very difficult to physically read the unbroken text and I find it dificult to follow an argument if it is not organised into paragraphs. Would you be able to edit so that one might more easily ingest your contribution ? Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

As a week has gone by without changes, I have taken the liberty of putting your wall of text into paragraphs, and putting in bold key points that actually deal with the question. It still remains the case that most of the start and the end does not deal with the question, which has nothing to do with how to become a Christian. It takes as understood that the person is a Christian. Answers that do not confine themselves to the scope of the question may be closed down. If you disagree with my edits, just roll back to what you originally had.

Thank you Anne, I’m trying to overcome a sixth grade education. It’s a slow process at my age, I thank you for editing my answer. I couldn’t answer Nigels comment on not being able to understand what I had written Anne with your help now he can. Shalom יהרה
